# Cron : Setting alternative minutes

Tags: cron

I need to run 2 scripts alternatively and as fast as possible.

Is there a way to have one script run on the even minutes of an hour and the other on the odd minutes.

Short of writing all the minutes out by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
0-59/2 * * * * first_script
1-59/2 * * * * second_script
```

Answer (score 0):

Why *not* just write out the minutes by hand? It will probably be clearer than trying to do anything clever - and only take about as many characters as posting this question.

I'm a big fan of "dumb" solutions which will obviously work, over trying to be clever.

Another alternative is to have one script which runs both of the others, one after another - then just run *that* one every other minute (0, 2, 4, ...)

Comment: "And only take about as many characters as posting this question." that made laugh as i thought the same thing after posting the question ^_^